# Postgis ST_Distance (Minimum Distance Calculation)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a geometry of type polygon , I am calculating minimum distance of a POINT may be inside of polygon geometry(made up of 360 points as a closed geometry) or outside of polygon geometry with ST_Distance method of postgis , I am getting exact distance when POINT is outside the geometry but getting 0 as Distance if POINT is inside the geometry , I want minimum distance from the point with the closest point of polygon geometry whether the POINT is inside the geometry or outside the geometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want the distance to the polygon shell, or the exterior ring. If you have a POLYGON try finding the distance to `ST_ExteriorRing(poly_geom)`. For MULTIPOLYGONs, see [manual page for ST_ExteriorRing](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_ExteriorRing.html).

Answer (score 2):

If your point is inside the polygon, then its distance from it is zero. It sounds like you want to calculate the distance from the edge of the polygon.

In that case you actually want to create a geometry that is a line, not a polygon, that is the same as the border of the polygon. Then your ST_Distance from your point to that line will be the result you are looking for.